# (OpenLayers) ReferenceError: ol is not defined

Tags: openlayers-3, systemjs, angular-cli

I'm working on Angular-CLI based project.
I need to include OpenLayers3 into my project using `systemjs`.

When I setup `systemjs` on my project for including Openlayers javascript file I had error `ReferenceError: ol is not defined`.

This is my system-config.ts file

```
const map: any = {
  'ol': 'vendor/openlayers/dist/ol.js'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'tether': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
  },
  'vendor/ng2-slimscroll': {
    defaultExtension: 'js',
  },
  'ol': {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
};
```

This error happens, but I still find that `ol.js` file has been called in my browser network debugger.

Also, this error gone when I define `ol.js` using regular `<script>` tag in head of my index page.

Comment: I too am having this problem. Any luck fixing it?

Comment: I've linked it using script tag in index.html file, that's how I got it working.
But, if I use SystemJS ol will not be recognized for some reason.
I'm guessing that because ol script needs to load before SystemJS.